# How to obtain Changeset of an activity?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool, clearcase-ucm

We are able copy to clipboard changeset of our activities.

But often we need to get changeset of our team member's activities.

We are able to see it through GUI. but we would like to copy the list of changeset to some text file.

Is it possible to get changeset using cleartool?

I was trying with following command but still it fails

```
V:\>cleartool lsactivity -l "PBI#503# to Model"\@My_PVOB
```

This is the error i got :

> cleartool: Error: Unable to determine VOB for pathname "My_PVOB".

V: is the drive where my integration stream is mapped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify activity ID instead of activity name (headline).
"PBI#503# to Model" seems like the activity name .

Comment: Thanks buddy. Yeah i have used the name.

Answer (score 2):

"PBI#503# to Model" is what is called the **headline** of the activity.

See [`cleartool chactivity`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_chactivity.htm) for instance:

> Changing the headline for an activity does not affect **its name (its unique identifier)**.
>   For information about changing the activity's name, see rename.

[image: example of an activity]

You can list all the activities of a stream and then format each changeset, as in [this thread](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=57224) (extract of the code):

```
my $istream = $ENV{CLEARCASE_STREAM};

my ($branch_name) = ($istream =~ /(.+)\@/);
my $change_set = join "\n",
sort map { / {4}(m:\[^\]+|.+\/vobs)?(.+)\@\@/i; $_ = $2 }
grep { /$branch_name[\/\]0-9+$/o }
qx{cleartool lsactivity -long $activity};
```

> The `$change_set` scalar will have the changed elements list without the `@@` extension or the `M:`, `/vobs/` prefix

Whatever your script language, the idea remains to list all activities within a stream:

```
cleartool lsact -in aStream@\aPVob -fmt "%n\n"
```

(That list the *names* only of the activities, not the headlines)

And then, do your `lsact -l` for each activity *name* found.