# Is there an equivalent of "rational synergy tasks" in "rational clearcase"?

Tags: clearcase, cm-synergy

We have the concepts of tasks in synergy. (we can create a task and associate our changes with that task).
Is there something similar in Rational clearcase?
as of now we just checkOut the files we need to edit , and check them in.
But If i want to search a set of related files for a CR, i cannot search it (this is where having a task helps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [ClearCase UCM](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/c_choose_diff.htm), you have the notion of [activities](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/u_props_activity.htm).

An activity contains a change set, which lists all the modified versions (created by a checkout/checkin on an element - file or directory).

[image: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21146901&aid=3]

Comment: WHat I want is to associate maybe 5 files with one task/activity, so that when i search a task/activity, it should give me the 5 files checked in

Comment: @user2256404 sure: simply set an activity as the current one (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9764851/6309), and checkout/checking 5 files: you will see them in the change set of that activity (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/8926682/6309 for instance, or http://stackoverflow.com/a/12247220/6309).

Comment: thanks VonC, I think thats what can be done, Now I will try out how it works, thanks a lot for providing the right direction to begin with :)