# Obtain change set of an activity with cleartool without active view

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

How can I obtain the list of changed files, given that I have an activity name (and also a project and stream name)?

This is what I tried:

```
cleartool lsact -l someActivity
```

But it returns:

```
cleartool: Error: Unable to determine VOB for pathname ".".
```

I suppose I should be in the correct view in order to get the contents. Is it also possible to retrieve all content without being in a view?

I obtained `someActivity` with an `cleartool lsproj`, then an `cleartool lsstream -s -in someProject` and then `cleartool lsact -in someStream`. I can do all these `cleartool` invocations without being in a view, so I'd like to obtain the changeset.

I'm found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926328/how-to-obtain-changeset-of-an-activity) but the answer only works when in a view. For the record, I'm not confusing the ID with the headline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would at least need to add the pvob in which that activity was created:

```
cleartool lsact -l someActivity@/vobs/aPVob  # Unix
cleartool lsact -l someActivity@\aPVob       # Windows
```

[`cleartool lsact`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsactivity.htm?lang=en) can use the current view if you don't specify any pvob:

> If you specify a simple name and the current directory is not a project VOB, this command assumes that the activity resides in the project VOB associated with the stream attached to the current view.
>   If the current directory is a project VOB, that project VOB is the context for identifying the activity.

`lsact` would also need a view if you want ClearCase to resolve the path of each version (resolved using the current view path).
Otherwise it would list extended pathnames for each version.